# Cannot access pod through LoadBalancer Azure Kubernetes Service

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

Yesterday i deployed my webapi to AKS, alongside this pod i also created a LoadBalancer.
For some reason i cannot call my api from Postman without giving the error:

> Error: connect ETIMEDOUT {{external ip of the loadbalancer}}:8080

This is my deployment.yml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: neume-billing-service-deployment
  labels:
    app: neume-billing-service
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: neume-billing-service-pod
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: neume-billing-service-pod
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: neume-billing-service-container
          image: neume.azurecr.io/neume:v2
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
```

And this is the service.yml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: neume-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: neume-billing-service-pod
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    targetPort: 80
  type: LoadBalancer
```

This is the `kubectl describe pod` command:

```
Name:             neume-billing-service-deployment-7dc454b957-b9vtb
Namespace:        namespace-workflow-1683420009400
Priority:         0
Service Account:  default
Node:             aks-agentpool-39303421-vmss000003/10.224.0.4
Start Time:       Sun, 07 May 2023 12:34:02 +0000
Labels:           app=neume-billing-service-pod
                  pod-template-hash=7dc454b957
Annotations:      <none>
Status:           Running
IP:               10.244.0.8
IPs:
  IP:           10.244.0.8
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/neume-billing-service-deployment-7dc454b957
Containers:
  neume-billing-service-container:
    Container ID:   containerd://b4e24117d6998222f638b9b43a926348f725dabf40799a61d9f4cdada492797b
    Image:          neume.azurecr.io/neume:80bc1072755113ebb4b39249d9b738ffbd769bd0
    Image ID:       neume.azurecr.io/neume@GITHUB.SHA
    Port:           80/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Sun, 07 May 2023 12:34:16 +0000
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-frgpd (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             True 
  ContainersReady   True 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  kube-api-access-frgpd:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age   From               Message
  ----     ------            ----  ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  43m   default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) had untolerated taint {node.kubernetes.io/network-unavailable: }. preemption: 0/1 nodes are available: 1 Preemption is not helpful for scheduling.
  Normal   Scheduled         42m   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned namespace-workflow-1683420009400/neume-billing-service-deployment-7dc454b957-b9vtb to aks-agentpool-39303421-vmss000003
  Normal   Pulling           42m   kubelet            Pulling image "neume.azurecr.io/neume:80bc1072755113ebb4b39249d9b738ffbd769bd0"
  Normal   Pulled            42m   kubelet            Successfully pulled image "neume.azurecr.io/neume:80bc1072755113ebb4b39249d9b738ffbd769bd0" in 4.458762571s (12.044207816s including waiting)
  Normal   Created           42m   kubelet            Created container neume-billing-service-container
  Normal   Started           42m   kubelet            Started container neume-billing-service-container
```

And this is the describe command for the service:

```
Name:                     neume-service
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=neume-billing-service-pod
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       10.0.178.196
IPs:                      10.0.178.196
LoadBalancer Ingress:     20.23.207.47
Port:                     <unset>  8080/TCP
TargetPort:               80/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  31656/TCP
Endpoints:                <none>
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:
  Type    Reason                Age   From                Message
  ----    ------                ----  ----                -------
  Normal  EnsuringLoadBalancer  16m   service-controller  Ensuring load balancer
  Normal  EnsuredLoadBalancer   16m   service-controller  Ensured load balancer
```

If i click on my service in the AKS dashboard and go to the 'Pods' tab, i see no pods listed for this service.

Whenever i run the `kubectl get pods` command, it says my pod is running just fine.

None of the already existing questions on Stack Overflow seem to help me so i hope someone can tell me what i am doing wrong here.

This is a project to get familiar with Kubernetes running in the cloud so i am not too worried about the ip-adresses being exposed in this question.

Comment: In the `kubectl describe pod` output is a `FailedScheduling` warning, which implies there's nowhere to actually run the Pod.  That's causing the Service to have nothing to bind to (`Endpoints: <none>`).  Do you need to configure the cluster autoscaler, or otherwise cause there to be more nodes?

Comment: Can you share the output of `kubectl get ns` ? Just wondering if your pods and Services are in same namespace?

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshots you have posted, it has been observed that deployments are in *namespace-workflow-1683420009400* namespace and service are in *default* namespace. To establish connection between the services and pods, both should be in namespace or have to configure dns names to connect services across different namespaces.
Refer to this link [access service from different namespace | 8gwifi.org](https://8gwifi.org/docs/kube-externalname.jsp) for connect services across different namespaces.

> Q. If i click on my service in the AKS dashboard and go to the 'Pods' tab, i see no pods listed for this service.
> Whenever i run the  `kubectl get pods`  command, it says my pod is running just fine.

To see the pods in the AKS dashboard, follow below process.
[image]

In portal, AKS cluster > workloads  > pods and select required filters.
[image]
To see services, go to services and ingresses.
[image]
[image]